# Making a sticky footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm trying to make a sticky footer but I can't seem to quite get it right. I really don't know how to describe this without showing some screen shot and some css. Here it is.

Right now my footer seems to be fixed because it will sit over content but I do not have `fixed position` set to it. Here is a screenshot of what happens

[image]

I would obviously like the footer to be pressed down by the content. Here is the css for the footer and the container:

### Footer CSS

```
.footer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

### CONTAINER

```
body {
  color: $base-text-color;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: $base-background-color;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 18px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

### APPLICATION HTML

```
<body>
  <%= render 'shared/top_bar' %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= render 'shared/errors' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
</body>
```

Hopefully this is enough info. Thanks for the help!

Comment: try to add `padding-bottom: 40px;` to `.container`

Comment: Doesn't seem to help. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: look at answer.

Comment: take a look at example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) you have to apply margin bottom to body that is height of footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given code I would do like this, where I set the `container` to full viewport height, subtract margin and footer height from it, and drop the absolute position.

This will keep footer at bottom when content is small, push it down when content grows.

One can use `flexbox` for this as well, though as long as the footer's height is known, this is the simplest and work very well cross browsers.

```css
html, body {
  color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 18px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 18px - 40px);
}
.footer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
    Container<br>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

couple of issues here :

1. don't give the container min-height of 100%;
2. dont give the body height of 100%;
3. give the container of the footer position:relative;
   and make yourself an habbit to always giv the parent of a positioned absolute element, "position:relative";

   ```
   body {
    color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:pink;
    border :  6px solid black;
    position:relative;
   }

   .container {
     max-width: 1200px;
     margin: 18px auto 0;
     text-align: center;
   }

   .footer {
     height: 40px;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     text-align: center;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your body does not fill the screen. You can set this:

```
body{ min-height: 100vh; position:relative;}
```